# Disable partners key in url bar

Tags: firefox, google, privacy

How I can disable in Google `client=ubuntu` (in DDG `t=canonical`) in Firefox 47?
See screenshot:

[image]

UPD: 
That's all what i find about subj,

`>strings /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so | grep "client=" -n`

`208606:  GetCacheSession for client=%s, policy=%d`

but more interesting about Canonical partners. Seems, installing FF from official repo can negatively affect your right to privacy.

Comment: See if you can uninstall `xul-ext-ubufox`.

Comment: @DKBose i purge this pkg, but client name present

Comment: Also, duckduckgo include `canonical` string [screenshot] (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/cecro1yft0xean8/Apps/Shutter/%C3%90%C2%92%C3%91%C2%8B%C3%90%C2%B4%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%90%C2%BB%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%90%C2%BD%C3%90%C2%B8%C3%90%C2%B5_110.png)

Comment: Hmmm... if that's really a problem for you, install Firefox 47 direct from Mozilla (http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/). That's what I'm using (for other reasons). It doesn't show "client name" in the search bar for Google. I don't use DDG.

Comment: Bad idea install not from repo.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is a "do not track" function. Firefox does have something that you could try and use.

See [link](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/dnt/)
It's disabled by default.

The Do Not Track feature is turned off by default. To turn it on:

```
Click the menu button and choose Options.
Select the Privacy panel.
Click manage your Do Not Track settings.
Check Use Do Not Track.
Close the about:preferences page. 
Any changes you've made will automatically be saved.
```

see: The [official mozilla site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-turn-do-not-track-feature)

Comment: DNT enable, but client name present [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/xrr8wvg7opaj2ai/Apps/Shutter/test%20-%20%C3%90%C2%9F%C3%90%C2%BE%C3%90%C2%B8%C3%91%C2%81%C3%90%C2%BA%20%C3%90%C2%B2%20Google%20-%20Mozilla%20Firefox_109.png)

Comment: Don't forget "individual websites are not required to respect it" - If you really want it to be completly without notice who you are maybe try using some kind of [sandbox](http://www.sandboxie.com/?FirefoxTips).