# Google collects data over ubuntu

Tags: firefox, canonical, privacy

So I was browsing and just typed "Ubuntu" over my top bar. The Google URL mentions: client=ubuntu

I deleted cookies, even disabled the Ubuntu plug-in in Firefox (presuming this was the problem) but there was no change. If you remove the client=ubuntu from the URL, you can still see the results you want, so why is there such a thing?

I'm pretty sure i have never encountered such a thing in other Linux distros. I think this is a major privacy flaw (if not used intentionally). Is Google collecting data over Ubuntu, or Ubuntu just gives data to Google?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/784733/40581 and http://askubuntu.com/q/577286/40581

Comment: Now continue at https://panopticlick.eff.org/ and read up what actually leaks out of your browser by default.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a (significant) privacy flaw. The browser sends a User-Agent string with each request anyway. For example, Firefox running on Ubuntu sends the following string with each request:

> `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0`

*All the web sites* that you visit using Firefox on Ubuntu know that you are running Ubuntu (or a derivative such as Linux Mint).

Comment: Yes but if someone opens wireshark, then he can easily read the search string without even bothering to look the headers . Why other linux distros block it and Ubuntu lets it?

Comment: Google is accessed over HTTPS. One cannot intercept the search string using Wireshark or other such tools. All one can see is that the computer made a TCP connection to google.com on port 443.